# The origin 'ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge' failed to allow a cross-origin font resource

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-edge, parcel

if i change my host to a custom one, then i get the error above. This only happens in edge
I have tried to build other application in different techs to see if it was my language but its not

```
 {
"name": "openlayers",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
 "scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "parcel index.html --host development.landwebni.gov.uk --port 9095",
"build": "parcel build --public-url . index.html"
 },
 "author": "",
"  license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
"app-root-path": "^3.0.0",
"authenticate": "^0.1.5",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-upgrade": "^1.0.1",
"commonjs": "0.0.1",
"config": "^3.2.5",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
"document-ready": "^2.0.2",
"eazy-logger": "^3.0.2",
"fs": "0.0.1-security",
"jquery": "^3.4.1",
"leaflet": "^1.6.0",
"ol": "^6.1.1",
"ol-contextmenu": "^4.0.0",
"ol-hashed": "^2.0.0",
"ol-layerswitcher": "^3.5.0",
"proj4": "^2.6.0",
"sidebar-v2": "^0.4.0",
"simple-datatables": "^2.1.9",
"simple-node-logger": "^18.12.24",
"winston": "^3.2.1",
"winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.4.1"
 },
  "devDependencies": {
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
   "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4"
  },
  " description": ""
}
```

Comment: Your above code example is not giving any idea about the issue. if possible then try to provide a code that we can try to run with the Edge browser to reproduce the issue. Also, try to provide detailed information about your project and the version of Edge and build of Windows OS. I tried to find the information about an error and found that enabling the IPV6 protocol can help to solve the issue. Ref: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/90033-enable-disable-ipv6-windows.html

Comment: it does. it clearly states when i change from the default localhost to a custom host

Comment: Please provide the necessary information which I stated in my previous comment. It can help to narrow down the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: resolved it myself

Comment: From your last comment, it looks like you solved the issue. I suggest you post your solution as an answer and try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question. It can help other users in future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.